# Crear tabla PIVOT Mensual SQLServer

Tags: sql, transact-sql

Buen día.
Necesito crear una tabla PIVOT agrupada y por mes con subquery. La sentencia es la siguiente.

```
SELECT F.FicEmpr AS 'Agrup', MONTH(F.FicFech) AS 'Month', ROUND(ISNULL((B.Aus*100.0 / A.Lab),0),2) AS 'Percent'
FROM FICHAS F 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FA.FicDiaL = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Lab' 
        FROM FICHAS FA
        WHERE MONTH(FA.FicFech) = 7
        AND YEAR(FA.FicFech) = 2022
        AND FA.FicEmpr= F.FicEmpr
) A
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FB.FicNovA = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aus'
        FROM FICHAS FB
        INNER JOIN FICHAS3 F3 ON FB.FicLega = F3.FicLega AND FB.FicFech = F3.FicFech AND FB.FicTurn = F3.FicTurn
        WHERE FB.FicDiaL = 1 
        AND MONTH(FB.FicFech) = 7
        AND YEAR(FB.FicFech) = 2022
        AND FB.FicEmpr = F.FicEmpr
        AND F3.FicNove NOT IN (601)
) B
WHERE F.FicLega > 0 AND MONTH(F.FicFech) = 7 AND YEAR(F.FicFech) = 2022 AND F.FicDiaL = 1 
GROUP BY F.FicEmpr, A.Lab, B.Aus, MONTH(F.FicFech)
```

El resultado es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo esperado debería ser lo siguiente. Columnas mensuales con sus respectivos valores. Sin tener que filtrar el mes en la consulta SQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alquien puede orientarme, agradecido de antemano. Saludos

Comment: Tal vez [este link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) te provea algo de orientación.

Comment: Ok. Voy a revisar. Gracias